# What is the meaning of 气 in 贵族气？

Tags: meaning

They are remembering their 小学时候。

。。。，班里那个贵族气十足的男生，。。。

zdic.net has 气 5）人的精神状态 a person's spiritual state

maybe this 气 just means 'style, like' and so 'air, manner'?

...,班里那个贵族气十足的男生,... that male student with a totally noble air,...

Is this the same 气 as in 怪里怪气？

Comment: why not "aristocratic (lordly, nobleman's) air" ?

Comment: Where did you read this? Don't you think it is awkward?

Comment: This is from my HSK6 textbook (北京语言大学出版社）. I cannot judge whether or not the style is good or bad, I'm just a learner! I'm happy if I can understand it!

Answer (score 4):

> [《汉语大词典》气 29](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/hydcd/262453v.html)
>
> 作风 style
>
> 习气 habits

贵族气 noble style

怪里怪气 strange/weird style

They all mean style.

Answer (score 2):

氣 can mean: air/ aura

> ***[aura](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aura)** : (noun)*
>
> *the distinctive atmosphere or quality that seems to surround and be generated by a person, thing, or place.*

Chinese like to use the word '氣' to describe a perceived quality of someone, something or some place

Examples:

- 此人豪氣十足 - This person is full of aura of pride
- 此劍寒氣迫人 - The sword's radiate air of chilling cold
- 此地鬼氣陰森 - This place emit ghostly aura

> **贵族气**十足的男生 means " Boys who are full of **aura of nobility**

The character 氣 is wildly used in many compound words, like : 氣勢，氣度，氣質，氣息. All related to 'air of/ aura of'(perceived quality)

Answer (score 1):

氣 --> 氣質 temperament / manner

or 氣派 imposing style

Answer (score 1):

(16) 指人、物的属性或一地的天然特点 [character]。如:气秀(气质优美);气昏(气昏混浊);气品(指万物);气习(气质,习性);气孱(气质虚弱)

http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/xs/6C14.htm